# How to upgrade the sklearn library in sagemaker

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, amazon-sagemaker

I noticed my Sagemaker (Amazon aws) jupyter notebook has an outdated version of the sklearn library.

when I run `! pip freeze` I get:

```
sklearn==0.0
```

and when I run (with python) `print(sklearn.__version__)` I get

```
0.24.1
```

I'm not sure which one is my real version but I need 1.0.0 in order to use the `from_predictions()` method.

But when I am trying to run `! /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade sklearn` I am getting the following output:

> Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (0.0) Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (from sklearn) (0.24.1) Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1
> in
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.5.3) Requirement already satisfied:
> joblib>=0.11 in
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.0.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (2.1.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> numpy>=1.13.3 in
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.19.5)

This is a very pupular library so it's weird if sagemaker cant upgrade it. Anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding the difference between `sklearn` and `scikit-learn`, have a look at https://towardsdatascience.com/scikit-learn-vs-sklearn-6944b9dc1736.
In short: They refer to the same package, but sklearn is a dummy project on PyPi that will in turn install scikit-learn.

Comment: did you find a way to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to update sklearn to version 0.24.2 via the following command:

```
!conda update scikit-learn --yes
```

To further update it, you probably have to also update Python, which is version 3.6 in the current conda_python3 kernel on Sagemaker.

It also looks promising to create your custom conda environment, as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-add-external.html